# Word2Vec + LSTM Good Training and Validation but Poor on Test

Tags: python, keras, nlp, lstm, word2vec

currently I'am training my Word2Vec + LSTM for Twitter sentiment analysis. I use the pre-trained GoogleNewsVectorNegative300 word embedding. The reason I used the pre-trained GoogleNewsVectorNegative300 because the performance much worse when I trained my own Word2Vec using own dataset. The problem is why my training process had validation acc and loss stuck at 0.88 and 0.34 respectively. Then, my confussion matrix also seems wrong. Here several processes that I have done before fitting the model

Text Pre processing:

1. Lower casing
2. Remove hashtag, mentions, URLs, numbers, change words to numbers, non-ASCII characters, retweets "RT"
3. Expand contractions
4. Replace negations with antonyms
5. Remove puncutations
6. Remove stopwords
7. Lemmatization

I split my dataset into 90:10 for train:test as follows:

```
def split_data(X, y):
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, 
                                                        y,
                                                        train_size=0.9, 
                                                        test_size=0.1, 
                                                        stratify=y,
                                                        random_state=0)
    return X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test
```

The split data resulting in training has 2060 samples with 708 positive sentiment class, 837 negative sentiment class, and 515 sentiment neutral class

Then, I implemented the text augmentation that is EDA (Easy Data Augmentation) on all the training data as follows:

```
class TextAugmentation:
    def __init__(self):
        self.augmenter = EDA()

    def replace_synonym(self, text):
        augmented_text_portion = int(len(text)*0.1) 
        synonym_replaced = self.augmenter.synonym_replacement(text, n=augmented_text_portion)
        return synonym_replaced

    def random_insert(self, text):
        augmented_text_portion = int(len(text)*0.1) 
        random_inserted = self.augmenter.random_insertion(text, n=augmented_text_portion)
        return random_inserted

    def random_swap(self, text):
        augmented_text_portion = int(len(text)*0.1)
        random_swaped = self.augmenter.random_swap(text, n=augmented_text_portion)
        return random_swaped

    def random_delete(self, text):
        random_deleted = self.augmenter.random_deletion(text, p=0.5)
        return random_deleted

text_augmentation = TextAugmentation()
```

The data augmentation resulting in training has 10300 samples with 3540 positive sentiment class, 4185 negative sentiment class, and 2575 sentiment neutral class

Then, I tokenized the sequence as follows:

```
# Tokenize the sequence
pfizer_tokenizer = Tokenizer(oov_token='OOV')
pfizer_tokenizer.fit_on_texts(df_pfizer_train['text'].values)

X_pfizer_train_tokenized = pfizer_tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(df_pfizer_train['text'].values)
X_pfizer_test_tokenized = pfizer_tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(df_pfizer_test['text'].values)

# Pad the sequence
X_pfizer_train_padded = pad_sequences(X_pfizer_train_tokenized, maxlen=100)
X_pfizer_test_padded = pad_sequences(X_pfizer_test_tokenized, maxlen=100)

pfizer_max_length = 100
pfizer_num_words = len(pfizer_tokenizer.word_index) + 1

# Encode label
y_pfizer_train_encoded = df_pfizer_train['sentiment'].factorize()[0]
y_pfizer_test_encoded = df_pfizer_test['sentiment'].factorize()[0]

y_pfizer_train_category = to_categorical(y_pfizer_train_encoded)
y_pfizer_test_category = to_categorical(y_pfizer_test_encoded)
```

Resulting in 8869 unique words and 100 maximum sequence length

Finally, I fit the into my model using pre trained GoogleNewsVectorNegative300 word embedding but only use the weight and LSTM, and I split my training data again with 10% for validation as follows:

```
# Build single LSTM model
def build_lstm_model(embedding_matrix, max_sequence_length):
    # Input layer
    input_layer = Input(shape=(max_sequence_length,), dtype='int32')
    
    # Word embedding layer
    embedding_layer = Embedding(input_dim=embedding_matrix.shape[0],
                                output_dim=embedding_matrix.shape[1],
                                weights=[embedding_matrix],
                                input_length=max_sequence_length,
                                trainable=True)(input_layer)
    
    # LSTM model layer
    lstm_layer = LSTM(units=128,
                      dropout=0.5,
                      return_sequences=True)(embedding_layer)
    batch_normalization = BatchNormalization()(lstm_layer)
    
    lstm_layer = LSTM(units=128,
                      dropout=0.5,
                      return_sequences=False)(batch_normalization)
    batch_normalization = BatchNormalization()(lstm_layer)

    # Dense model layer
    dense_layer = Dense(units=128, activation='relu')(batch_normalization)
    dropout_layer = Dropout(rate=0.5)(dense_layer)
    batch_normalization = BatchNormalization()(dropout_layer)
    
    output_layer = Dense(units=3, activation='softmax')(batch_normalization)

    lstm_model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)

    return lstm_model

# Building single LSTM model
sinovac_lstm_model = build_lstm_model(SINOVAC_EMBEDDING_MATRIX, SINOVAC_MAX_SEQUENCE)
sinovac_lstm_model.summary()
sinovac_lstm_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                               optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
                               metrics=['accuracy'])
sinovac_lstm_history = sinovac_lstm_model.fit(x=X_sinovac_train,
                                                  y=y_sinovac_train,
                                                  batch_size=64,
                                                  epochs=20,
                                                  validation_split=0.1,
                                                  verbose=1)
```

[image]

The training result:
[image]

The evaluation result:
[image]
[image]

I really need some suggestions or insights to have a good accuracy on my test

Comment: use regularization and batch normalization.

Comment: I used dropout, do you mean is l2 regularization ? And where should I put the batch norm ? Is the end of each LSTM layer ? or end of the Dense layer ?

Comment: you can use L1 or L2 regularization or both. Use batch normarlization for second LSTM layer and first Dense layer.

Comment: Okay let me try, and one question, previously, I have experimented with my own Word2Vec trained using my own data, the result is worse than using the pre trained Word2Vec GoogleNewsVector300negative,  I still wondering if we want to train our custom Word2Vec with our own data, should use the whole text data or just the training data?

Comment: GoogleNewsVector300negative trained over large corpus so  pre trained Word2Vec GoogleNewsVector300negative will be better. you have to use whole text data in your corpus for finding word2vec.

Comment: okay thanks for the answer, in my current model, should I set the pre trained word embedding trainable to False ?

Comment: Okay, I have implemented your suggestions where I put the batch norm after the second LSTM layer (LSTM->BatchNorm) and after the first dense layer (Dense -> Dropout -> BatchNorm), and I have implemented both L1 or L2 regularization on both LSTM layer, but the result is much worse, where val loss suddenly jump into 10.xxx

Comment: Try different value of L1 and L2 regularization or I am saying do hyperparameter tuning with different value of L1 and L2. Finding right value for L1 and L2 is an art. comment your L1 and L2 values. Also perform regularization for dense layer.

Comment: Okay I'll try, but seeing the confusion matrix, is it possible the validation data is imbalanced ?

Comment: It may be possible. If data is imbalanced then you have to change your metrics from accuracy to precision or recall. Or you can use some techniques like oversampling or smote to avoid the data imbalanced problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without reviewing everything, a few high-order things that may be limiting your results:

- The `GoogleNews` vectors were trained on media-outlet news stories from 2012 and earlier. Tweets in 2020+ use a very different style of language. I wouldn't necessarily expect those pretrained vectors, from a different era & domain-of-writing, to be very good at modeling the words you'll need. A well-trained word2vec model (using plenty of modern tweet data, with good preprocessing/tokenization & parameterization choices) has a good chance of working better, so you may want to revisit that choice.
- The `GoogleNews` training texts preprocessing, while as far as I can tell never fully-documented, did not appear to flatten all casing, nor remove stopwords, nor involve lemmatization. It didn't mutate obvious negations into antonyms, but it did perform a statistical combinations of some single-words into multigram tokens instead. So some of your steps are potentially causing your tokens to have less concordance with that set's vectors – even throwing away info, like inflectional variations of words, that could be beneficially retained. Be sure every step you're taking is worth the trouble – and note that a suffiicient modern word2vec moel, on Tweets, built using the same preprocessing for word2vec training then later steps, would match vocabularies perfectly.
- Both the word2vec model, and any deeper neural network, often need lots of data to train well, and avoid overfitting. Even disregarding the 900 million parameters from `GoogleNews`, you're trying to train ~130k parameters – at least 520KB of state – from an initial set of merely 2060 tweet-sized texts (maybe 100KB of data). Models that learn generalizable things tend to be *compressions* of the data, in some sense, and a model that's much larger than the training data brings risk of severe overfitting. (Your mechanistic process for replacing words with synonyms may not be really giving the model any info that the word-vector similarity between synonyms didn't already provide.) So: consider shrinking your model, and getting much more training data - potentially even from other domains than your main classification interest, as long as the use-of-language is similar.

Comment: So commenting on your first thought, so you are saying that I should train my own Word2Vec with my own dataset ? CMIIW; For the second thought, I have done several pre processing text for my twitter text you can see the pre processing code from the given code and what do you mean by "note that a suffiicient modern word2vec model, on Tweets, built using the same preprocessing for word2vec training then later steps, would match vocabularies perfectly." ? can you please explain more detail in that ? But is it possible that I still have some residual noisy words after pre processing ?

Comment: For your third thought, I did the text data augmentation to increase my training samples from 2K into 9K, and I tried train own Word2Vec model it seems gives worse validation result than fine tuning the pre trained Google word embedding

Comment: Okay, I found other pre trained word embedding that is `GloveTwitter` is it will be more suitable for my case ?

Comment: If you have sufficient data, I think it's likely enough a custom-traned word2vec model will work better that it's worth a try. If you previous tries haven't worked, maybe there wasn't enough data, or other errors in training were made. (For example, your ~2000 tweet-sized texts is perhaps 100 to 1 million times less text data than you'd want for a strong word2vec model.

Comment: If you train your w2v model on same tokenized text as you'll be classifying, then it will necessarily have learned words for every word you need (excepting rare words typically ignored in word2vec training to improve the model). Your prior process, as described, risks having more unknown words that aren't in `GoogleNews` set – perhaps because their usage was minimal 10+ years ago in news articles, or you've done different preprocessing (like more-aggressive case-flattening).  Your process also (via your lemmatization) discards word forms that `GoogleNews` might have perfectly good vectors for.

Comment: Did you check to ensure the augmentation, specifically, was helping? That sort of mechanistic word-replacement isn't something I'd expect to do much to help up for a lack of true variety in the training set – especially since the use of word-vectors *already* should be helping the model recognize similar expressions using slightly-different words.  The random swaps & deletes might even be hurting! I would make sure to test whether it's helping separately from any other choices, and only (maybe) apply/test it *after* doing other kinds of better-grounded tuning/data-collection.

Comment: It's possible the `GloveTwitter` will work better or worse than `GoogleNews` - the only way to know is to try both & compare results. But depending on the exact source, those `GloveTwitter` vectors might still be 2 to 8 years old - still not reflecting of latest word usage trends, especially terms & names that only became prominent (for example) during the COVID pandemic. So there's still a fair chance a custom model (given enough recent training data) could do better.

Comment: Okay, thanks to your advices, I tried using custom pre-trained word2vec by mapping the pre trained weight to my own word tokens and turned out the result is very good! You can see, I have updated the model performance that has good training and validation. But why it is still poor on the test set ?

Comment: And 2 additional question, is it better if I use the whole data fit in the tokenizer ? Because I'am afraid a token words in test that is not exist in the tokenizer will be ignored ; Secondly, so I should use the whole data to be mapped with the pre trained word embedding ? (Including test data)

Comment: I tried without the augmentation data, the performance is worst, so it seems my data augmentation can help leverage the performance

Comment: Because you still have a large model & small data set, you are probably still massively overfitting. If there are salient words in the test set that are never learned by earlier steps, that is a problem, and indicates, as mentioned above, you need more training data. Some people do use all data for 'unsupervised' steps (where the models are only learning from shape of data, not from you feeding them 'right' answers) - whether that's appropriate for your evaluations depends on your ultimate goals & deployment scenarios.

Comment: It's good you tested the augmentation. It still seems sketchy to me when you still have other data-sufficiency issues, and would be best to test last, separately. (Maybe whatever lift it's providing disappears when underlying dearth-of-data problems solved another better way.) And each of the alternate modifications could be evaluated separately: the synonym replacement seems a plausible help to me, but addingremoving/swapping random words could plausilby change meanings, clouding the field for the network's learning.

Comment: Okay let me try, btw, what do you mean "be best to test last" ?

Comment: I tried to not using the random insert, delete, and swap but the performance is much worse tho

Comment: That surprises me, but if random perturbations are improving things, that increases the liklihood actually good, real texts could help even more. "best to test last" means that rather than considering it a core technique, try other more tangible things 1st – especially more real organic data, but also other parameter tuning. Then at the end, try creating such fake, synthetic texts to see if it still helps.

Comment: So I can conclude that, my case is actually due to the lack of training data, I think I can consider this is as my limitation and weakness for my case

Comment: Okay, interesting, I used the pre-trained Glove Twitter weight and I got test accuracy above 70%

Comment: Wow, I implement cross validaiton using K=10, the test performance increase that the loss is reduce and more stable to 1.xx , how is that helped ?

Comment: I don't understand "Wow, I implement cross validaiton using K=10, the test performance increase that the loss is reduce and more stable to 1.xx , how is that helped ?" at all.

Comment: I mean, I implemented the scikit-learn cross validation with K=10, somehow the test loss is better than the validaton_split keras, with the validaiton_split, the average test loss is 2.xx - 5.xx, with cross validation, the test loss can reach 0.xxx

Comment: Sounds like something that, if it remains a mystery, would best be served by a new focused question, that shows exactly the contrast between two approaches, with full code for each, that you expected would be similar. (I'd expect that the mere exercise of constructing that would reveal some salient difference in magnitudes, or error in evaluation, that explains the discrepancy.)